# How to implement a custom LoadErrorHandlingPolicy for exoplayer

Tags: android, error-handling, exoplayer

I want to implement a custom load error handling policy for the exoplayer. On medium I found [this](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/load-error-handling-in-exoplayer-488ab6908137) great article which introduce me to build my custom error handling police. Now I'm stuck by implementing
`getRetryDelayMsFor(dataType: Int, loadDurationMs: Long, exception: IOException?, errorCount: Int)`  method.

I don't understand which exception exactly I have to catch on `SomeNetworkException` and `NoConnectivityException`

Has anyone implemented a custom load error handler too and is will share their knowledge with me?

Answer (score 3):

Check for `HttpDataSource.HttpDataSourceException` inside `getRetryDelayMsFor` method as such:

```
public long getRetryDelayMsFor(int dataType, long loadDurationMs, IOException exception, int errorCount) {
    // checking if it is a connectivity issue
    if (exception instanceof HttpDataSource.HttpDataSourceException) {
        return 5000; // Retry every 5 seconds.
    } else {
        return C.TIME_UNSET; // Anything else is surfaced.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaSource builder allows you to set a LoadErrorHandlingPolicy to define how the player handles errors
Chech out this code

```
   MediaSource mediaSource = new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .setLoadErrorHandlingPolicy(getMyErrorHandlingPolicy())
                    .createMediaSource(uri);
```

and

```
 private static LoadErrorHandlingPolicy getMyErrorHandlingPolicy(){
//        LoadErrorHandlingPolicy loadErrorHandlingPolicy = new DefaultLoadErrorHandlingPolicy();

    return new LoadErrorHandlingPolicy() {
        @Override
        public long getBlacklistDurationMsFor(int dataType, long loadDurationMs, IOException exception, int errorCount) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getRetryDelayMsFor(int dataType, long loadDurationMs, IOException exception, int errorCount) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getMinimumLoadableRetryCount(int dataType) {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

DefaultErrorPolicy retries 3 or 6 times before propagating the error.

```
   /** The default minimum number of times to retry loading data prior to propagating the error. */
 public static final int DEFAULT_MIN_LOADABLE_RETRY_COUNT = 3;
  /*** The default minimum number of times to retry loading prior to failing for progressive live streams.
 public static final int DEFAULT_MIN_LOADABLE_RETRY_COUNT_PROGRESSIVE_LIVE = 6;
```

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/d458b90/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultLoadErrorHandlingPolicy.java